# Can't get Hyper-V to work with the Android Emulators visual studio

Tags: hyper-v, visual-studio, emulator

This is the second machine I'm trying to get Hyper-V to work in combination with the Android Emulators and still haven't found the answer. What am I missing?

Configuration:

```
AMD Ryzen 9 9300x Processor, 32 Gb Ram, 1Tb SSD. 
BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends Inc. P4.20, 6-11-2020
```

In PowerShell used these commands:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V


FeatureName      : Microsoft-Hyper-V
DisplayName      : Hyper-V Platform
Description      : Provides the services that you can use to create and manage virtual machines and their resources.
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Enabled
CustomProperties :

PS C:\Windows\system32> get-service | findstr vmcompute
Running  vmcompute          Hyper-V Host Compute Service
PS C:\Windows\system32> wmic OS Get DataExecutionPrevention_Available
DataExecutionPrevention_Available
TRUE

PS C:\Windows\system32> wmic OS Get DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy
DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy
2
```

Even set the above value to 1 with wbemtest as described here:

---

```
EDIT
Value is back to 2 after reboot
```

---

---

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/determine-hardware-dep-available.

The emulators all use the x86 but still says I should turn on Hyper-V:

[image]

Value = TRUE meaning Hyper-V is active and turned on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For all that have this problem. Here's the solution.

After reading this page: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?pivots=windows#accel-issues-win

I executed the following commands:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online                                                                                                                                                   
FeatureName      : Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
DisplayName      : Hyper-V
Description      : Provides services and management tools for creating and running virtual machines and their resources
                   .
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Enabled
CustomProperties :

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName HypervisorPlatform -Online


FeatureName      : HypervisorPlatform
DisplayName      : Windows Hypervisor Platform
Description      : Enables virtualization software to run on the Windows hypervisor
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Disabled
CustomProperties :
```

Default so it seems the Hypervisor is disabled (why for crying out loud). The commands below enabled it. This should be in the Documentation and not hidden somewhere in a troubleshooting page.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All

Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False

PS C:\Windows\system32> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName HypervisorPlatform -All


Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False
```